# Loading time of a module is too high

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a custom extension in Magento 1.9. In the Profiler, it shows me that the loading time is too long.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl4G0.jpg

I can provide you the scripts from the files.

Does anyone know how I could fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

You posted this on reddit as well, so I'll give the same answer.

> The observer loops through all categories and makes a recursive call for subcategories.